# Shuffle and get ISO date from a file using shuf Unix command

Tags: bash

I am trying to fetch the ISO timestamp from a file using shuf command and store the timestamp in a variable.

I have the timestamp in the format date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0000
This timestamp I am storing in a variable using shuf command. However, all I get in the output is date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0000 instead of the actual datetime.

```
TIMESTAMP=$(shuf -n 1 dateTimestamp.txt)
echo $TIMESTAMP  //gives output as date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0000 instead of displaying the values for Y,m,d,H,M,S
```

```
dateTimestamp.txt file has below content.
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0530"
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0000"
```

How can I modify to get the correct timestamp fetched from the file using shuf command.

Comment: Try `TIMESTAMP=$($(shuf -n 1 dateTimestamp.txt))`. The file `dateTimestamp.txt` must come from a trusted source.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Nejat's comment for the solution, *to ensure the source is trusted*, you can build the temporary file on the fly and use it as your input.  You could place that in either /tmp or in ${HOME}/tmp or anywhere else you may prefer.

```
#!/bin/sh

INPUT="myShuf$$.txt"

cat >${INPUT} <<-!EnDoFfIlE
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0530"
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:+0000"
!EnDoFfIlE

TIMESTAMP=$($(shuf -n 1 ${INPUT}))
echo $TIMESTAMP
```